# Create an excel file from java code

Tags: java, excel

hi i would to create an excel file from a java code, i put this code on eclipse 
but nothing happen

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class TestPOI1 {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         //create the new workbook
         Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

         try {
                 //create the output stream to save the document on the hard drive
                 FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test1.xls");

                 //write the file onto the hard drive
                 workbook.write(output);

                 //finish it up by closing the document
                 output.close();
         } catch(Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }        
}
```

in the console, this message is written

Usage: BiffDrawingToXml [options] inputWorkbook Options:

-exclude-workbook            exclude workbook-level records

-sheet-indexes      output sheets with specified indexes

-sheet-namek          output sheets with specified name

and i can't found my excel file in the hard drive or in the file project.
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

That output does not come from the source you show here. So you must have been running something else, and run it incorrectly.
The source you list should write an empty xls file (maybe even an invalid one) to the same directory the program was started from.